# making focus invisible for radio buttons on click but focus should be visible on keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, accessibility

How do I make focus invisible for radio buttons only on click (focus should be visible through keyboard navigation)

disabling mouse down event or
using settimeout(()=>$(event.target).blur(),1) on mousedown 
is working but selection of radio buttons using arrow keys is not working when focus is from click.

so,whats the best way to make focus invisible for radio buttons only on click  without making arrow key selection unusable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

added event handlers for mousedown and blur as below

---------------  Template  -----------------

```
<input type="radio"
(mousedown)="removeOutline($event)"
(blur)="radioBlur($event)"/>
```

------Event Handlers -----------------

```
removeOutline(event: MouseEvent): void {
        $(event.target).addClass("focus");
    }

radioBlur(event: MouseEvent): void {
        $(event.target).removeClass("focus");
        if ($(event.target).attr("class") === "") {
            $(event.target).removeAttr("class");
        }
    }

 -----------css---------------
  .focus {
        outline: 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about

```
pointer-events: none;
```

or am i missing something?

Comment: i just want the focus to be disabled on click..by using "pointer-events:none" wouldnt click also gets disabled as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="inp" />
<input type="radio" class="rb" />
```

CSS:

```
.inp {
   display: block;
}

.rb {
 /*hide default outline*/
   outline: none;  
}

[type=radio]:not(:hover):not(:active):focus {
  /*set custom focus ring instead via box-shadow*/
    box-shadow: 1px 0 1px #c5c3c3 inset, -1px 1px 1px #c5c3c3 inset, 0px 0px 0 2px #fff, 0px 0px 0 3px rgb(100, 149, 237);
}
```

It will hide focus ring on hover and on click but display it when radio button getting focus via keyboard.

Here is link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqeo9xph/6/)

There is also a proposal for that kind of thing called focus-ring (currently only implemented in Firefox but there is [polyfill](https://github.com/WICG/focus-ring) for that.

Comment: its hiding the focus on hover and click,but when the moves leaves the radio button after clicking,the focus is still visible.Thanks anyway

Comment: @Moeed, sorry but I don't understand what do you mean. it does remove focus when you move focus into other element. Please the the update example on JSFiddle

Comment: ,when the radio button is clicked and mouse leaves the radio button(focus is not moved to other element),box shadow is still visible.i want to supress this as well.